# Como fazer para que depois de ler um arquivo "txt" ele ler outro em seguida

Tags: c++

Como fazer para depois de ler o arquivo `txt` verificar se tem um próximo arquivo `txt`, sei que para ler o arquivo basta:

```
ifstream Arquivo;
Arquivo.open("teste.txt");
while ()
{
   // leitura
}
```

Depois de ler este arquivo, verificar se tem outro arquivo, se tiver ele vai ler este arquivo, e assim sucessivamente.

Comment: Esses arquivos estarão na mesma pasta do executável?

Comment: sim, ou seria melhor criar uma pasta lá mesmo com esse arquivos?

Comment: Vai depender do que você deseja, mas por uma questão de organização, ter um diretório próprio para esses arquivos deve ser mais adequado.

Comment: concordo plenamente .

Comment: Não está muito claro na sua pergunta qual é de fato o problema. Por que fazer simplesmente `ifstream Arquivo1, Arquivo2; Arquivo1.open("teste.txt"); Arquivo2.open("teste2.txt");` não serve? Será que o que você quis dizer é que não sabe como encontrar o próximo arquivo/listar arquivos numa pasta (algo como essa pergunta do SOEN: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/612097/how-can-i-get-the-list-of-files-in-a-directory-using-c-or-c)?

Comment: @LuizVieira só pode ter ou não mais dois arquivo, o usuário joga cinco arquivo, por isso tem que ser algo genérico para ler os arquivos txt

Comment: Mas o problema não é ler os arquivos, e sim listá-los para a função de leitura, certo?

Comment: @LuizVieira realmente , quando ler um ele vai verificar se tem outro arquivo, se tiver ele vai ler este arquivo, e assim sucessivamente.

Comment: Ok, então edite a pergunta para deixá-la mais clara. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Uma forma de listar os arquivos é através das funções [`FindFirstFile`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa364418%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) e [`FindNextFile`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa364428(v=vs.85).aspx) (Windows):

```cpp
#include <windows.h> /* Para usar as funções de busca de arquivos */
#include <vector>    /* Para usar */
#include <sstream>   /* Para usar o Stringstream */
#include <iostream>  /* Para manipular a entrada/saída de streams */
#include <fstream>   /* Para usar o ifstream */
....
using namespace std;
...
vector<string> ProcurarArquivos(string diretorio) {
    vector<string> arquivos;                      /* Vetor que irá armazenar os resultados temporários */
    string busca = diretorio + "\\*.txt";         /* Cria o filtro, no diretório será encontrado somente arquivos .txt */
    HANDLE hFind;                                 /* Identificador da pesquisa */
    WIN32_FIND_DATA data;                         /* Estrutura que conterá informações dos arquivos */
    hFind = FindFirstFile(busca.c_str(), &data);  /* Procura pelo primeiro arquivo */
    if (hFind != INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE) {          /* Se a função não falhar */
        do {
            arquivos.push_back(data.cFileName);   /* Armazena no vetor o nome do arquivo encontrado */
        } while (FindNextFile(hFind, &data));     /* Procura pelo próximo arquivo */
    FindClose(hFind);                             /* Fecha o identificador da pesquisa */
    }
    return arquivos;                              /* Retorna o vetor como resultado */
}
```

Para ler o conteúdo do arquivo e retornar numa *string*, faça:

```cpp
string LerAquivo(string arquivo) {
    ifstream ifs;                                          /* Stream usada para fazer operações em arquivos */
    ifs.exceptions (ifstream::failbit | ifstream::badbit); /* Define quais exceções podem ser lançadas */
    try {                                                  /* Tenta executar o código abaixo */
        ifs.open(arquivo.c_str());                         /* Abre o arquivo */
        stringstream ss;                                   /* Stringstream que vai conter o resultado */
        ss << ifs.rdbuf();                                 /* Lê o buffer do stream e coloca no Stringstream */
        string str = ss.str();                             /* Coloca numa string o resultado do Stringstream */
        return str;                                        /* Retorna a string */
    }
    catch (ifstream::failure e) {                          /* Se houver erros em relação a leitura dos arquivos */
                                                           /* Fazer alguma coisa aqui caso ocorram erros */
        return "";                                         /* Retorna uma string vazia */
    }
}
```

Para obter o caminho da aplicação use a [função `GetModuleFileName`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683197(v=vs.85).aspx):

```cpp
string DiretorioDaAplicacao() {
    char buffer[MAX_PATH];                        /* Cria um buffer com tamanho máximo para um diretório */
    GetModuleFileName(NULL, buffer, MAX_PATH);    /* Para retornar o caminho completo do executável */
    int pos = string(buffer).find_last_of("\\/"); /* Captura a posição da última barra "/" */
    return string(buffer).substr(0, pos);         /* Extraí tudo desde o início até o ponto onde foi encontrado a barra "/" */
}
```

Para extrair somente o nome do arquivo, use a função:

```
string ExtrairNomeDoArquivo(string caminho) {
    int indice = caminho.rfind('/');              /* Encontra o índice da última ocorrência da barra "/" */
    return caminho.substr(indice + 1);            /* Extraí tudo a partir do índice da barra "/" */
}
```

**Nota**: Funciona somente no Windows, e há ocasiões em que essa função poderá falhar.

Exemplo de utilização:

```cpp
int main() {
    string Diretorio = DiretorioDaAplicacao();             /* Captura o diretório da aplicação */
    vector<string> arquivos = ProcurarArquivos(Diretorio); /* Cria um vetor que armazenará os o caminho dos arquivos encontrados */
    for (vector<string>::iterator i = arquivos.begin(); i != arquivos.end(); i++) { /* Faz a iteração sobre o vetor "arquivos" */
            string conteudo = LerAquivo(*i);               /* Coloca na variável o conteúdo do arquivo atual da iteração */
            string arquivo  = ExtrairNomeDoArquivo(*i);    /* Coloca na variável somente o nome do arquivo atual da iteração */

            cout << "Nome do arquivo: " << arquivo << endl;
            cout << conteudo << endl;
    }
    cin.get(); /* Espera o usuário digitar algo*/
    return 0;  /* Termina o programa */
}
```

Comment: um duvida não entendi o a parte de de listar os arquivos, vou listar os arquivos e só depois vou fazer a leitura. é isso mesmo?

Comment: @Rodolfo A ideia é essa sim. Você primeiro lista os arquivos `.txt` do teu diretório, depois num `for` você lê arquivo por arquivo.

Comment: estou encontrando problema no `for` e no `LerArquivo()` no `int main()`

Comment: @Rodolfo Que problema exatamente?

Comment: @Rodolfo Tinha esquecido de citar o *header* `fstream` que era necessário, tente rodar esse código: **http://pastebin.com/UtGsxZ03**, ele vai apenas listar os arquivos `.txt` da pasta da tua aplicação.

Comment: @Rodolfo Deu certo?

Comment: funcionou porem como vou fazer para ler os  dados  desse arquivos?

Comment: @Rodolfo Só chamar a função `LerArquivo` com o argumento `*i`, que é o arquivo atual da iteração, exemplo: **http://pastebin.com/Kbt6ZF1P**.

Comment: Teria como na parte que pesquisa os arquivos `txt` pegar o nome e armazenar em um vetor tipo `char nomeArquivo [50]`.

Comment: @Rodolfo Você já tem o caminho dos arquivos no vetor **`arquivos`**, se precisar extrair o nome,  você procura pela última `/`, e com o `substr`, você extrai o nome desse arquivo a partir do índice. Exemplo: **http://pastebin.com/tqHN3yUc**. Não é algo *100% seguro*, e só funciona no **Windows**, se precisar de algo mais elaborado, crie uma nova questão sobre isso. =)

Comment: @qmechaik está funcionando certinho, porém está complicado entender o código, por não ter muito conhecimento, não sei teria como comentar linha por linha da parte de listar os arquivo, ou não teria um alternativa mais simples de realizar esse mesma tarefa.

Comment: @Rodolfo Editei a resposta, tentei comentar o máximo que pude. Veja se agora consegue entender.

Answer (score 4):

Outra forma, como sugerido [na questão do SOEN](https://stackoverflow.com/a/612176/2896619) que eu mencionei nos comentários, é usar o cabeçalho "dirent.h". Ele é padrão no Unix e [pode ser baixado no Windows](http://www.softagalleria.net/download/dirent/) (e usado junto com o seu projeto - basta ter o arquivo de cabeçalho `dirent.h`). Assim, seu código fica mais independente do sistema operacional.

Um exemplo de uso:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

#include "dirent.h"

using namespace std;

vector<string> listfiles(char *sPath)
{
    vector<string> vRet;
    DIR *pDir = opendir(sPath);
    if(pDir != NULL)
    {
        struct dirent *pEnt;
        while((pEnt = readdir(pDir)) != NULL)
        {
            if(strcmp(pEnt->d_name, ".") != 0 && strcmp(pEnt->d_name, "..") != 0)
                vRet.push_back(pEnt->d_name);
        }
        closedir(pDir);
    }
    return vRet;
}

int main(void)
{
    vector<string> vFiles = listfiles("c:/teste/");
    char sFile[256];

    for(unsigned int i = 0; i < vFiles.size(); i++)
    {
        sprintf_s(sFile, 256, "c:/teste/%s", vFiles[i].c_str());

        ifstream oFile(sFile);
        string sData;

        getline(oFile, sData);

        printf("1a linha do arquivo {%s}: [%s]\n", sFile, sData.c_str());
    }

    return 0;
}
```